# Angular Material md-autocomplete with md-chips doesn't clear search if blank

Tags: angularjs, md-autocomplete, md-chip

I am using md-autocomplete inside an md-chips.  If I type 'a' and then select from the list, the control works correctly.

however, if i don't type any search string and simply select from the list (because i want min-length=0), then the control shows the chip and also shows the contents as my new search string??

http://jsfiddle.net/3t715vLw/

```
<md-autocomplete md-min-length="0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code take this part out `md-item-text="item"`
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3t715vLw/1/)